# What is wrong with this basic Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm watching a basic tutorial series on javascript and have been stuck on this super simple script for like close to 30 minutes now. I used an html validator and it all checks out with no errors. However, the code is still not behaving how it should according to the video.

When you type "click me" its supposed to show a dialog box saying 'please enter a real value into the box'. And when you enter a value in the field, it's supposed to substitute the title for whatever you entered.

Sorry for the simple nooby question

EDIT AGAIN: Thanks Arby. That got it working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Example</title>
  <script type="text/javscript">
    function substitute () {
        var myValue = document.getElementById(myTextBox).value;

        if (myValue.length == 0){
          alert('Please enter a real value in the text box!');
          return;
        }
        var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
        MyTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="title">JavaScript Example</h1>

  <input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
  <input type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="substitute()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you edit your question, adding actual code we can look at.

Comment: ^^^ Was just gonna say. Have you put through a *JavaScript* validator? Have you thrown it into a fiddle?

Comment: Welcome to SO,,See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask questions on SO

Comment: For stuff involving web languages, we commonly use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to test code, and link the fiddle into the answer. You can also post code within the question by indenting four spaces, or using CTRL+K after highlighting the lines of code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the snippet ;)

Comment: `MyTitle` isn't the same as `myTitle`, that could be an issue.

Comment: I changed the code and still won't execute properly. both of them are lowercase now to "myTitle

Comment: Read answer I posted, if it works in your environment (I tested in fiddle), mark as accepted, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found *some* issues with your code, just simple stuff that every beginner goes through (I did), I'll bullet them off:

- `MyTitle` isn't `myTitle`, JavaScript variables are case-sensetive.
- You should *stay away* from the `onclick` attribute; he's a bad influence. The point, inline JS is generally not a good idea.
- So I added an event listener event instead: `[...].addEventListener("click", callback);`
- Your DOM request to the input box used an undefined variable/object/etc. called `myTextBox`, instead of a string `"myTextBox"`.

Anyway, I made a JSFiddle for the code, so I could test it, so here is the link to the code with the edits I explained above: https://jsfiddle.net/Lktzw0Lh/

Comment: OK this is perfect. I can understand what your saying and don't know why the tutorial suggested in-line code if its not good practice. I know what the event listener does and how it refers back to the function "substitute" as well. What I don't understand, is what purpose ID'ing "submit" does. In javascript, green code acts as a word value sort of right? So what does ID do? is it something entirely different because the function we defined as "substitute" seem to be whats being called upon here.

Comment: @Aspen IDs are simply strings of arbitrary value (*id est* They can be anything you want), that uniquely identify the element. IDs can only be used once, on one element, *per se*. So you can, change the ID from "submit" to anything, and just change the reference in the script, and it will work the same. IDs are generally used to refer to a specific element, whether in CSS or JS. In the case of this code, it doesn't change anything, except make it referable by `document.getElementById("id")`.

Comment: I recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_id.asp) if you're new to HTML IDs and working with them

Comment: Inline JS is common in beginning tutorials because they don't need to explain linking a script, what an event listener is, what an event is, and all that fun stuff. But if you try to put extensive, long code in an inline script attribute, you start to get problems such as quotes working incorrectly, undefined stuff, etc. It is also *very* good practice to separate HTML, CSS, and JS, into separate files, to make code more organized and readable. Get in the habit of that, while you're still learning.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach - since you list jQuery in the tags for this - i have rejigged the code to take advantage of it. I put an onclick event handler on the button which, when clicked gets the value of the textbox and if it is empty - gives the alert. If it is not empty - it swaps the h1 text for the entered text and clears the text input and gives it focus so that you can re-enter new content.

Note that the click handler is in the javascript section and not inline js and also that with jquery - you can chain together commands that affect the same element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#testButton').click(function(){
   var myValue = $('#myTextBox').val();
   if (myValue == ''){
     alert('Please enter a real value in the text box!');$('#myTextBox').focus()
   }else{
     $('#title').text(myValue);$('#myTextBox').val('').focus()
   }
 })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="title">JavaScript Example</h1>

  <input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
 <button id="testButton" type="button">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```